# Get values from array of JSONs in JSON ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm trying to get values from JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 371,
    "city": "London",
    "name": "London Station",
    "trains": [
        {
            "id": 375,
            "number": "1023",
            "numberOfCarriages": "21"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get values from trains, like number and numberOfCarriages. I'm trying to get those values in React. My React code:

```
class ViewTrainsComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            station: []
        }
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                        <div className="row">
                            {/* <div>{this.state.station[0].trains[0].number}</div> */}
                        </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Am I doing it right? How can I get those values in render function?

EDIT.

Here is the response from API
[image]

Comment: How and where are you reading the JSON? Just because you create an object structure that matches the JSON doesn't mean it has any relation to or knows how to magically populate it with the values of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid setting and updating state directly with

`this.state = ...`

except when you are initializing it in the constructor.
Instead, use either [setState(](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)) function or the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

But I think your question is more about how to get the values of the trains in render function,
You can access those as

```
render() {
    return <div>{this.state.stations[i].trains[j].number}</div>
  }
```

so for the first train of first station i=0 and j=0 and for the second train in first station i=0 and j=1.
for the first train of second station i=1 and j=0 and for the second train in first station i=1 and j=1.

Comment: I guess it does not work in my case. I updated the question for more details

Comment: this.state = {
            id: this.props.match.params.id,
            station: []
        }
when are you setting the value for station ? are you passing it as a prop to this component? or are you fetching it from an API

Comment: if station is not an array then you access the trains as this.state.station.trains[j].number

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have multiple of those JSON objects coming from somewhere (a file, an API request, whatever), you can do:

```
this.setState({ stations: yourParsedJson })
```

since the data and your proposed component state are the same shape.